# Deep autoencoder in Keras converting one dimension to another i

Tags: python, vector, neural-network, keras, autoencoder

I am doing an image captioning task using vectors for representing both images and captions.

The caption vectors have a legth/dimension of size 128.
The image vectors have a length/dimension of size 2048.

What I want to do is to train an autoencoder, to get an encoder which is able to convert text vector into a image vector. And a decoder which is able to convert an image vector into a text vector.

Encoder: 128 -> 2048.

Decoder: 2048 -> 128.

I followed [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) tutorial to implement a shallow network doing what I wanted.

But I cant figure out how to create a deep network, following the same tutorial.

```py
x_dim = 128
y_dim = 2048
x_dim_shape = Input(shape=(x_dim,))
encoded = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x_dim_shape)
encoded = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(y_dim, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(512, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(x_dim, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input=x_dim_shape, output=decoded)

# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = Model(input=x_dim_shape, output=encoded)

encoded_input = Input(shape=(y_dim,))
decoder_layer1 = autoencoder.layers[-3]
decoder_layer2 = autoencoder.layers[-2]
decoder_layer3 = autoencoder.layers[-1]

# create the decoder model
decoder = Model(input=encoded_input, output=decoder_layer3(decoder_layer2(decoder_layer1(encoded_input))))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')


autoencoder.fit(training_data_x, training_data_y,
                nb_epoch=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(test_data_x, test_data_y))
```

The training_data_x and test_data_x have 128 dimensions.
The training_data_y and test_data_y have 2048 dimensions.

The error I receive while trying to run this is the following:

> Exception: Error when checking model target: expected dense_6 to have shape (None, 128) but got array with shape (32360, 2048)

dense_6 is the last decoded variable.

Comment: The reasons I think it is working in the tutorial is that they train their autoencoder with equal dimensions on input and output, while I want to train my autoencoder to go from one dimension to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Autoencoders

If you want is to be able to call the `encoder` and `decoder` separately, what you need to do is train the whole autoencoder exactly as per the tutorial, with `input_shape == output_shape` (`== 128` in your case), and only then can you call a subset of the layers:

```
x_dim = 128
y_dim = 2048
x_dim_shape = Input(shape=(x_dim,))
encoded = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x_dim_shape)
encoded = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(y_dim, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(512, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(x_dim, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input=x_dim_shape, output=decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(training_data_x, training_data_x, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=256, shuffle=True, validation_data=(test_data_x, test_data_y))

# test the decoder model
encoded_input = Input(shape=(y_dim,))
decoder_layer1 = autoencoder.layers[-3]
decoder_layer2 = autoencoder.layers[-2]
decoder_layer3 = autoencoder.layers[-1]

decoder = Model(input=encoded_input, output=decoder_layer3(decoder_layer2(decoder_layer1(encoded_input))))
decoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
eval = decoder.evaluate(test_data_y, test_data_x)
print('Decoder evaluation: {:.2f}'.format(eval))
```

Notice that, when calling `autoencoder.fit()`, `x == y` in the arguments. This is how the auto-encoder would (normally) have to optimize the bottleneck representation (that you call `y` in your own code) to best fit the original image with less dimensions.

But, as a transition to the second part of this answer, notice that in your case, `x_dim < y_dim`. You are actually training a model to *increase* the data dimensionality, which doesn't make much sense, AFAICT.

### Your problem

Now reading your question again, I don't think autoencoders are any good for what you want to achieve. They are designed to **reduce** the dimensionality of the data, with a minimum of casualties.

What you are trying to do is:

1. **Render** a text to an image (what you call `encode`)
2. **Read** a text from an image (what you call `decode`)

In my understanding, while `2.` might indeed require some machine learning, `1.` definitely doesn't: there are plenty of libraries to write text on images out there.